# Esper rule language: fire rule only after condition is fulfilled for a certain time period

Tags: java, rule-engine, complex-event-processing, esper

I want to write a rule that fires when the heart rate is above 160 for 5 minutes. The rule I came up with is the following:

```
 EPAdministrator cepRule3 = cep.getEPAdministrator();
        EPStatement cepStatementRule3 = cepRule3.createEPL("select * from "
                + "HeartRate.win:time(5 min) "
                + "group by macAddress "
                + "having min(heartrate) > 160");
        cepStatementRule3.addListener(new rule3Listener());
```

My HeartRate class has the following fields:

```
int heartrate;
String heartratesTimestamp;
String macAddress;
```

The problem i'm facing is that this rule fires every time there is a heart rate above 160. Instead I want it to only fire when the heart rate remains above 160 for 5 minutes. How can I adjust this rule?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EPL:
every(HeartRate(heartrate>160) -> (timer:interval(5 min) and not HeartRate(heartrate<=160))

or simply with and in Java code:
 `EPStatement cepStatementRule3 = cepRule3.createEPL("every(HeartRate(heartrate>160) -> (timer:interval(5 min) and not HeartRate(heartrate<=160))");
        cepStatementRule3.addListener(new rule3Listener());`

Look up the EPL pattern syntax in the Esper documentation.

Comment: Could you write this in full because I don't understand the syntax of this rule. Thanks

Comment: Thank you, I have now the following rule: `"select * from pattern[every(HeartRate(heartrate>160) -> (timer:interval(5 min) and not HeartRate(heartrate<=160)))]"` but how can I include the group by macaddress like in my previous rule?

Comment: You could use a context partitioned by mac address, like this: create context PartitionByMac partitioned by macaddress from HeartRate; context PartitionByMac select * from pattern[every(HeartRate(heartrate>160) -> (timer:interval(5 min) and not HeartRate(heartrate<=160)));

Comment: When I do this and use the partition you suggested, the rule doesn't fire anymore. My rule is now `cepRule3.createEPL("create context PartitionByMac partition by macAddress from HeartRate", 
                "context PartitionByMac select * from pattern[every(HeartRate(heartrate>160) -> (timer:interval(5 min) and not HeartRate(heartrate<=160)))]");`. Without the context the rules works fine but then fires ofcourse for all macAddresses. What could the problem be?

Comment: Never mind found my problem. I should have created two seperate EPL statements. Thank you